# Subtime Text 2 - can't run windows command with spaces and quotes

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext2, sublimetext, command-line-interface

I have a small Python script generating a Windows command:

```
def quoted(s):
    return '"' + s + '"'

import os
path = 'C:\\Program Files\\SumatraPDF\\SumatraPDF.exe'
params = ' -page 5 '
arg = 'D:\\Dropbox\\Final Term\\Final Draft.pdf'
cmd = quoted(path) + params + quoted(arg)
print cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

This doesn't run inside Sublime Text 2 (pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>):

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -page 5 "D:\Dropbox\Final Term\Final Draft.pdf"
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

but runs if I manually copy and paste the command (outputted by this script) into `cmd.exe`.

How do I make it work?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks

Answer (score 2):

That's an issue with space in your filepath (it's a problem on Windows). os.system() opens a command shell, and this behavior is inherited from your command shell.  If you open a "DOS box" and type the
same things at it, you'll get the same results - it's the Windows command shells that require quoting paths with embedded spaces. You should use another pair of quotation marks.

Comment: Didn't understand the last sentence - can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: try: path = '""C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"'

Comment: Doesn't work :( The complete command was: `""C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"" -page 5 "D:\Dropbox\Final Term\Final Draft.pdf"`

Comment: try ""C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"" -page 5 ""D:\Dropbox\Final Term\Final Draft.pdf""

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1913064/1368703), 
The sublime part is ancillary, but from a python interpreter, you can test that os.system will work if you use double quotes around the whole string. However, you don't need any quotes if you use [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows) (it is smart enough to figure that out).

For example

```
>>> cmd = '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe""'
>>> os.system(cmd)
```

or

```
>>> cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe'
>>> Popen(cmd)
```

By the way, from looking at your comments, don't double quote the path, double quote the entire command `""path to exe with spaces" "arg1" "arg2" "arg3""`, and you really don't need all the inner quotes, but they won't hurt, meaning it should work with  `""path to exe with spaces arg1 arg2 arg3""`

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, the `subprocess` module is probably the best solution.

However, it's worth noting that MS Windows still provides the old 8.3 filename translation for compatibility with old MS-DOS programs. You can find the translations by running `dir /X` in `cmd.exe`, which will typically show that `C:\Program Files` can be referred to as `C:\Progra~1`.

In your case, the following...

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Progra~1\\SumatraPDF\\SumatraPDF.exe'
params = ' -page 5 '
arg = 'D:\\Dropbox\\FinalT~1\\FinalD~1.pdf'
cmd = path + params + arg
print cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

...ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` is deprecated. The correct thing to do is Wyrmwood's mentioned `Popen`, and to separate the arguments:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([
    "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe",
    "-page", "5",
    "D:\Dropbox\Final Term\Final Draft.pdf"
])
```

You can then build your command by having a list and `.extend`ing it with your arguments. You can add (`+`) `sys.argv` on to take from the command line, and so on.

---

There are also other helpful functions in `subprocess` that will allow you to, say, get the output from a command (`checkoutput`). You probably just want `subprocess.call`.

If you use plain `process = subprocess.Popen(...)`, be prepared to call `process.wait()` to prevent early termination.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. Quote the executable path and then quote the whole string.

```
def quoted(s):
    return '"' + s + '"'

import os
path = "C:\\Program Files\\SumatraPDF\\SumatraPDF.exe"
params = ' -page 5 '
arg = 'D:\\Dropbox\\Final Term\\Final Draft.pdf'

cmd = quoted(quoted(path) + params + arg)
print(cmd)

os.system(cmd)
```