# os.system() executes wrong command

Tags: python, os.system

This is simple but I can't figured it out myself.
I'm developing a python tool for installing/uninstalling software without GUI. Everything works fine for the installation part but for some reason python throws an error from `os.system()` command for un-installation one. The other strange thing is it works perfectly when the same command is submitted via `.bat` file.

So if I submit:

```
os.system(r"D:\builds\vray\2014_uninstall.bat")
```

And in the .bat file I have this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\3dsmax 2014 for x64\uninstall\installer.exe" -uninstall="C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\3dsmax 2014 for x64\uninstall\install.log" -uninstallApp="V-Ray for 3dsmax 2014 for x64" -gui=0
```

...everything works fine.

But when I try to submit that command directly from os.system like this:

```
cmd = r'"C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\3dsmax 2014 for x64\uninstall\installer.exe" -uninstall="C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\3dsmax 2014 for x64\uninstall\install.log" -uninstallApp="V-Ray for 3dsmax 2014 for x64" -gui=0'
os.system(cmd)
```

It gives me this error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Here is a quick video that shows this weird behavior:
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1bfo1YxQ5Yfl1KP7EvfN0oLdenPAbErCW

Python version is 3.6.5, Windows is 10.0.16299.431

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27662747/1008142

Comment: I suggest you use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.sytem()` which has problems with paths and filenames that have space characters in them.

Comment: [`system` on Windows is really dumb.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters)

Comment: I got the same behavior with subprocess.call and subprocess.check_call as well. Will try to wrap the entire string with extra quotes to see if that would help.

Comment: Same thing with additional quotes, it just doesn't work. I am realizing that in my commands there are three strings with white spaces - maybe those commands works for two strings but not for three.